# Remove Parenthesis and Quotes from items in tuple

Tags: python, easygui

I am creating a Python program to generate a returns report. I have created a simple GUI for my program that allows the user to select the categories they would like to run the report for. The only issue is that in the GUI, each selection has (' ',) format. I was wondering how I could remove these from the options so it displays only the words? I have attached a screenshot of the GUI and the code for the GUI is below.

```
cat_SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Inventory.Category FROM Inventory"
cursor.execute(cat_SQL)
result = cursor.fetchall()
final_result = [list(i) for i in result]
string_result = [tuple(map(str, eachTuple)) for eachTuple in final_result]
text = "Select Category(ies): "
title = 'Returns Summary'
choices = string_result
cat_output = multchoicebox(text, title, choices)
```

[GUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fostS.png)

Comment: Do you know what ``tuple(map(str, eachTuple))`` does in your code?

Comment: It would be better to stop converting tuples to strings than to try to remove tuple formatting from an existing string.

Comment: I have tried just passing choices = final_result but that formats the options as [u' ']

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Comment: Line 5 (which MikeScotty mentioned) converts your map objects to tuples. By using `''.join()` you can return strings instead.